# Alternative to sending data to view in List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently learning .NET MVC and almost finished my first application. At the minute I am trying to send multiple list of data to the view, each list with mulitple fields and then populating multiple tables with these lists.
For example i have an animals table in my db, i want to pull all records from the table and display all of them in a table in the view. I also have a db treatment table and want to display all records from the table in a separate unrelated table in the view

In the past I have declared  a List in the viewmodel (below) and populated this list as required, but it is not very useful as it only takes two fields, Value, and Text

```
             public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> treatmentList { get; set; }
```

Im not sure if I have made my problem very clear. Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may consider two approaches:

1. Using an ViewBag to store the IEnumerable, so you do not need to put it in the view model
2. You may consider use an Select List

`public SelectList treatmentList { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Am I right in saying that the selectlist can only carry two different fields? such as value and text?

Comment: If you want to construct an dropdownlist option, yes it should be like this. However, if you use selectlist for other purpose, it can definitely have different items